# I am having this error,"cannot import name gTTS"

Tags: python

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

tts=gTTS(text="Both are great",lang="en")
tts.save("both.mp3")
os.system("mpg12 both.mp3")
```

Comment: reinstall gTTS but same error

Comment: could it be possible that your script is named "gtts.py" ?

Comment: my script name is gtts.py

Comment: Then rename it.

Comment: my script is rename but same error occurred. No any change of error. So please help me something else

Comment: Check for a stray gtts.pyc file and remove it.  If it still fails you'll have to check your sys.path and what exactly gets imported as gtts

Comment: I have installed gtts in python folder

Comment: Please edit your post to add the following informations : os, python version, how you installed gtts (note that "I have installed gtts in python folder" is _not_ a valid description of how you installed it - please describe _exactly_ what you've done), where is your script and what else you have in this directory, what your sys.path is (add "import sys; print sys.path") at the top of your script and run it), and what exactly is imported as "gtts" (add "import gtts; print gtts" at the top of your script and run it).

Comment: import sys;                                                                             print(sys.path);                                                                                     ['', '/home/pi', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages']

Comment: import gtts
(Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import gtts
ImportError: No module named 'gtts' )                                                         .                                                                                                print(gtts)
(Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(gtts)
NameError: name 'gtts' is not defined )                                            .

Comment: Please edit your post with instead, and explain how you "installed" gtts

Comment: sudo pip install gTTS command use it

Comment: PLEASE update your post instead of posting comments...

Answer (score 1):

1. You should try renaming the file and run again.
2. You have saved as "both.mp3" and trying to play file "mpg12 both.mp3" make the correction!

   ```
   os.system("both.mp3")
   ```